# What should be the data type to be used? Decimal or Advance

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oop, mvp

In a wage processing system which employees MVP pattern We have Model classes `WageInfo`,  `EarningInfo`, `DeductionInfo` and `AdvanceInfo` and entity class `Advance`. (With several other classes)

`EarningInfo` and `DeductionInfo` has a composition relationship with `WageInfo` (contained in WageInfo) and also since Advance amount is a part of wages (paid in advance)  I've modeled the relationship of `Advance` with `DeductionInfo` as aggregation because finally it becomes a deduction to the wages (advance amount should be deducted from wages).

```
public class DeductionInfo
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public decimal LoanInstalmentAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal UniformInstalmentAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal InsuranceInstalmentAmount { get; set; }      
    public decimal AdvanceAmount { get { return Advance.Amount; } set { Advance.Amount = value; } }

    public Advance Advance = new Advance();
}


 public class Advance
{
    public int AdvanceID { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnteredDate { get; set; }
}
```

So when I create a `DeductionInfo` object I simply assign a value to `AdvanceAmount` property and I'm not initializing other properties of `Advance` class in this instance.

My question is, in DeductionInfo class, since the advance amount is just an amount, is it worth to use `decimal` property over an Advance field?

Comment: You are right. either user a plain property. or use Advance Object Property itself

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Advance` type instead of just a `decimal`. The `EnteredDate` property on that is probably being set during the save process. That would be good for keeping track of when the Advance was given, and also differentiating between multiple advances of the same amount.

As an aside, I'm surprised there is not a `PayedBack` property on the `Advance` to denote when it was resolved.

On it's own, it wouldn't matter which you use, however there is a lot of other information being recorded when an advance is made. Without that other class, then there's no way to keep track of that information.

Comment: what do you mean by `PayedBack`? Actually the advance amount is finally deducted from the NetWage to calculate BalanceWage which is the actual amount would paid.

Comment: OK, well if it's fully repaid the next time the employee gets paid, then there's no need for the `PayedBack` property. It was me not understanding your business rules, but I would still leave that comment in there as an example of another piece of information that might need to be tied to what you're thinking is just a simple decimal value.